# Cache is not initialized, cannot RetrieveEntry error for Selenium/ChromeDriver when I click Download Link

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an error where I try to click a download link in headless chrome and I get the error below.

> ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(191)] Cache is not initialized. cannot
>   RetrieveEntry.

The above happens everytime it gets to click the download link.

Code works fine when I'm not running as headless

Also get other errors when I run as `--headless`, They are below not sure if related:

> [0911/115517.146:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The Content Security Policy
>   'default-src 'self';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline';' was delivered in report-only mode, but does not
>   specify a 'report-uri'; the policy willhave no effect. Please either
>   add a 'report-uri' directive, or deliver the policy via the
>   'Content-Security-Policy' header." storage (0)
>
> [0911/115517.620:INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "[Report Only] Refused to evaluate
>   a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source
>   of script in the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Any thoughts? Using latest version of ChromeDriver, Python 3.7, latest Selenium module. Code just doesn't work when I run as headless and gets all the way to the point where it should click a download link and put file in download path. Works fine on non-headless chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution was found. Essentially you need to build the ChromeDriver doing so:

```
def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(driver, download_dir):
    # add missing support for chrome "send_command"  to selenium webdriver
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

The full details can be found in the following threads:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2454